# How to get signal wires to a rotating object (steering wheel)?

Tags: wiring, automotive

How do engineers get electrical signals to a steering wheel? For example, in Formula 1 they have a whole screen they need to supply with data, and a normal car has to connect the buttons somehow. How would one get signals to a rotating steering wheel?

Comment: Steering wheels have a limited range of rotation. Flexible cable and and a bit of slack management should be all that is necessary.

Comment: I think either EEVblog or bigclive has taken apart a steering wheel thingy.  This is the first thing I found, it's not the one I'm looking for, but it may be even better: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/formula-1-steering-wheel-teardown/

Comment: This is the one I was looking for: "Inside a car clock-spring module (steering wheel wiring interface)" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IK06vAlQpOs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most auto manufacturers use what is called a "clock spring" to carry signals from the rotating part of the steering wheel to the steering column.  They use these vs. other methods like a slip-ring due to reliability concerns.  Since important safety signals, like airbag deployment, come through here in most vehicles, the reliability and also complexity of a slip-ring system makes them unsuitable for this application.

[image: Automotive clock spring from https://www.newegg.com/standard-motor-products-csp106-air-bag-clockspring/p/N82E16888823009?item=N82E16888823009&source=region&nm_mc=knc-googleadwords-pc&cm_mmc=knc-googleadwords-pc--pla--airbag+and+seat+belt+parts-_-N82E16888823009&gclid=CjwKCAjwpMOIBhBAEiwAy5M6YKWuEnAHoOsb7680PcK9BgDqvsAE6gamoiaeqUZA1Soooh8MzlNupBoC5ksQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds]

This is just a long coil of flexible wire that winds/unwinds as the wheel is turned.

Answer (score 0):

They usually use a device called a [slip ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_ring).

[image: Typical slip ring]

A device like this is installed in the heart of the rotating device. It has static wires on one side, and a rotating set of wires on the other. The signals get transfered through brushed contacts. This is somewhat comparable to how potentiometer wipers work. Because of this, you can trivially transfer power, analog signals, and even data, without having to transform your signals somehow. Designers can almost treat the device like a normal wire connecting the static and rotating components.

Obviously, brushed contacts wear out, so the life span of devices like these is somewhat limited. They also have serious limits on the rotation speed. This isn't too relevant on a steering wheel, but could be very serious on motor driven applications. Current limits are also usually rather low, but there is usually a bigger (and much more expensive) solution available.

Comment: No, most likely a slip ring would not be used, due to the reliability issues you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

There might be many solutions, but at least one solution  found in standard consumer automotive products is to use a durable flat flex cable that is wound to a spiral shape to allow the spiral to loosen or tighten depending on which way you turn the steering wheel.

As serial buses are quite normal these days, it only takes a few wires to have power supply and data bus for everything in the wheel. And a couple of wires more to detonate the airbag as they may not be behind a bus. Likely in the order of 4 to 7 wires.